Error: Non-compatible actual argument in a feature call in Eiffel code for reading and writing files
I am working on a program in Eiffel that reads data from an input file, processes it, and writes the results to an output file. The input file contains: ID, name, birthdate, address, and the number of family members. The program calculates the financial assistance based on the age and the number of family members.
However, I am encountering an error:
Non-compatible actual argument in a feature call
This error happens when I try to use the split method to separate the values in the input file line.
Here’s my Eiffel code
class
    PERSON_ASSISTANCE

create
    make

feature {NONE} -- Initialization
    make
        local
            input_file, output_file: PLAIN_TEXT_FILE
            id, name, birthdate, address: STRING
            family_members_count: INTEGER
            current_year, birth_year, age, financial_assistance: INTEGER
            line: STRING
        do
            create input_file.make_open_read("input.txt")
            create output_file.make_open_write("output.txt")

            -- Read input file line by line
            current_year := 2024
            from
                input_file.read_line
            until
                input_file.end_of_file
            loop
                line := input_file.last_string

                -- This is where I encounter the error
                id := line.split(",").item(1)  -- Error occurs here
                name := line.split(",").item(2)
                birthdate := line.split(",").item(3)
                address := line.split(",").item(4)
                family_members_count := line.split(",").item(5).to_integer

                -- Extract birth year and calculate age
                birth_year := birthdate.substring(1, 4).to_integer
                age := current_year - birth_year

                -- Calculate financial assistance
                financial_assistance := (age * 10) + (family_members_count * 10)

                -- Write result to output file
                output_file.put_string(id + ", " + name + ", " + financial_assistance.out + "€%N")

                input_file.read_line
            end

            input_file.close
            output_file.close
        end
end

The error occurs when I attempt to call split(",")

The {STRING}.split method takes a {CHARACTER} and not a {STRING} as argument. The documentation here
So, the split call should be like:
line.split(',')


Louis M has the answer, but it's worth noting that when you need to get multiple values from the same string, splitting repeatedly is foolish. Instead assign the results to a LIST[STRING].
Assuming you called that list information.
                information := line.split(',')

                id := information.item(1) 
                name := information.item(2)
                birthdate := information.item(3)
                address := information.item(4)
                family_members_count := information.item(5).to_integer

This has the benefit of giving you only one place to make an error.
